# SQL Select criteria

Tags: sql

I have two tables temp_number and temp_port, I want to select only those number which are having only port name is 'ip sub' and want to exclude those numbers are having both port names or port name is 'local loop'

```
    temp_number
    -----------------------------------
    numberid  | name
    -----------------------------------
    1         | abc
    2         | def
    3         | ghi
    -----------------------------------  

    temp_port
    -----------------------------------
    portid    | numberid  | name
    -----------------------------------
    1         | 1         |  local loop
    2         | 1         |  ip sub
    3         | 2         |  local loop
    4         | 3         |  ip sub
    -----------------------------------  



    CREATE TABLE temp_number  
    ( numberid number(10),  --pk
      name varchar2(50));  

     CREATE TABLE temp_port  
    ( portid number(10),     --pk 
      numberid number(10),   --fk
      name varchar2(50));  

    insert into temp_number values(1,'abc');
    insert into temp_port values(1,1,'local loop');
    insert into temp_port values(2,1,'ip sub');
    insert into temp_number values(2,'def');
    insert into temp_port values(3,2,'local loop');
    insert into temp_number values(3,'ghi');
    insert into temp_port values(4,3,'ip sub');

What I tried : 
select n.name, p.name from temp_number n, temp_port paving 
where n.numberid=p.numberid  and p.name not in ('local loop');

    actual result:
    -----------------------------------
    name | Name
    -----------------------------------
    abc  | ip sub
    ghi  | ip sub


    expected result:
    -----------------------------------
    name | Name
    -----------------------------------
    ghi  | ip sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this filtering

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.name, p.name
FROM temp_number t, temp_ports p
Where t.numberid=p.numberid AND t.numberid NOT IN
    (SELECT s.numberid FROM temp_port s WHERE s.name = 'local loop')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a filter NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.name, p.name
  FROM temp_number t
 INNER JOIN temp_port p
    ON p.numberid = t.numberid
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM temp_port s
                    WHERE s.numberid = t.numberid
                      AND s.name = 'local loop')
```

This way, if for some number there's at least a 'local loop' port, it filters out that number

Comment: This will still include it if it has both entries (`ip sub` and `local loop`).

Comment: @Eric if it has both entries, it means 'local loop' exists for that numberid. NOT EXISTS filters that numberid out

Answer (score 0):

Select those having 'ip sub' port name only and no other port names:

```
select n.*
from 
temp_number n
join
(select numberid,   
sum(case when name = 'ip sub' then 1 
      else 0 end)  ipCount,
count(*) totalCount
from temp_port
group by numberid  ) t 
on n.numberId = t.numberId
where t.ipCount = totalCount
and   t.ipCount > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the numbers by just doing:

```
select numberid
from temp_port
group by numberid
having min(name) = 'ip sub' and min(name) = max(name);
```

If you actually want the name, joining in the name is pretty easy:

```
select n.numberid, n.name
from temp_number n join
     temp_port p
     on n.numberid = p.numberid
group by n.numberid, n.name
having min(p.name) = 'ip sub' and min(p.name) = max(p.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

we can eliminate the not needed entries by using sub query as follows.

```
Select a.name, b.name 
From temp_number a
left join temp_port  b on b.numberid = a.numberid
Where b.name = 'ip sub'
and a.numberid not in (Select c.numberid from temp_port c where c.name <> 'ip sub')
```